# How correctly to design a login screen?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new in android development, and I develop an app, in which will be log in with the help of firebase (Sign in with google, facebook, twitter, gitHub and anonymous). But I don't know how to correctly design logic and architecture by login screesn for my app.

Now, I created auth_activity.xml in which :

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btn_group_social"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/mail_pass">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_google"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_google_256dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="@null"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_facebook"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_facebook_256dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="@null"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_twitter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_twitter_256dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="@null"/>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_gitHub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_git_hub_256dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="@null"/>

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mail_pass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="50dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:text="or"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:hint="@string/email"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:hint="@string/password"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_access"
        android:text="@string/access"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/forgot_your_password"
        android:textColor="@color/bg_screen1"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Skip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
```

Also, I attempted to create an activity in which I implemented google sign in, but I do not think that it will be true to create in one activity all the ways login (google, facebook and so on).
I do not quite understand how to organize it properly.

Probably you have a completed project in which have a login.

Thanks.

Comment: Android studio has default activity called Login activity. You coould try to add it and see if it works. It automatically creates the layout file and some logic.

Comment: I really don't think anyone will provide you with a implemented project, if you're new to Android. You won't learn. I would look at more completing the functionality first and then do your design to how you would like it, look at things such as [this](https://sourcey.com/beautiful-android-login-and-signup-screens-with-material-design/) and [this](http://graphicdesignjunction.com/2014/03/sign-in-login-app-ui-designs/). But one word of advice, you'll need a more complete knowledge of layouts/widget attributes to create custom layouts. I wouldn't expect an out-the-box code to be to your use case

Comment: Just like @HonorLT mentioned, just go to your app folder on the Project, left click, new->Activity->Login Activity

Comment: When I say "completed project" i mean i want see example. And about the functional and logic, I do not know how to correctly write authorization for each social network. It needs to be written in separate activities or fragments and so on? Because the examples that you give off about it do not tell, and the official documentation does not tell you how to combine it together. –

Answer (score 0):

[image: Like this]
As mentioned in the comments you can add an activity like below

Answer (score 0):

https://sourcey.com/beautiful-android-login-and-signup-screens-with-material-design/

this might help you!!!

In order to make everything work we need to add a couple of dependencies to the build.gradle file in your app directory. ButterKnife is optional, but we like to use it to clean up our Java code a bit.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
}
```